# JSON doesn't support the Schema of POST MongoDB and POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, react-native, postman

```
Object {
"VariableRep": Array [
"101-1",
"101-2",
"101-3",
"102-1",
"102-2",
"102-3",
"201-1",
"201-2",
"201-3",
"202-1",
"202-2",
"202-3",
],
"dateObservation": "2020/8/12
",
"essaiParcelle": "key1",
 "microParcelle": Array [
"101",
"102",
"201",
"202",
],
 "nameSerie": "Assess",
 "nbRepetition": "3",
 "variablesUnique": Array [
 Object {
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Carence en bore - % de surface parcellaire touchée",
  },
  ],
   }
```

The json I get does not insert into the postman I have to delete and modify some words like Array and commas

Is there a method to insert this json document on POSTMAN correctly a method to convert or a code generator on react automatically?

thanks

[image: screen from red error]

Comment: this is not JSON, this is why it's not working... until you don't tell us how you get this format, or the format name, we can't help (if not with some half solution, which will be probably broken since we don't know any cases except the one in the image)

Comment: const obs =  {
      nameSerie : inputObservation,
      essaiParcelle : selected1, 
      microParcelle : dataSet, 
      dateObservation : epoch,
      nbRepetition : number,
      variablesUnique : listCar,
      VariableRep : tabRep
      
    }

    console.log(obs). 

the result of variable is from state , input , arrays ect ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` does not output JSON, it outputs a human-readable, interactive, display of the contents of a variable. It is not intended for this purpose, and converting its output to JSON is going about things the wrong way.

To produce JSON using JavaScript, you can use [the `JSON.stringify` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).